# Is there a method to exception handle a bound error in a for loop of two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm unsure how to fix this error stating: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 13 out of bounds for length 13
    at p7_9.fillDeck(p7_9.java:23)
    at p7_9.(p7_9.java:13)
    at p7_9.main(p7_9.java:17)

I've tried adjusting the array size or initializing i = 1; instead but to avail. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
public class p7_9 {
    int cards = 13;
    int face = 4;
    private String[][] deck = new String[cards][face]; // The deck of cards
    private String[][] suits = new String[cards][face]; // used to print suits for deck
    private String[] shuffledDeck = new String[52]; // this is the deck that is dealt from
    private String[] shuffledSuit = new String[52]; // this is used to keep track of suits
    private String[] newCard = new String[5];    // What will be scored
    private String[] newSuit = new String[5];    // What will be scored

    private p7_9() {
        fillDeck();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p7_9 poker = new p7_9();
    }

    private void fillDeck() {
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < deck[cards].length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < deck[face].length; j++) {
                // Fills out the card values
                switch (i) {
                    case 10:
                        deck[i][j] = " Joker";
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        deck[i][j] = " Queen";
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        deck[i][j] = " King";
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        deck[i][j] = " Ace";
                        break;
                    default:
                        deck[i][j] = " " + (i + 1);
                        break;
                }

                switch (j) {
                    case 0:
                        suits[i][j] = "Spades";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        suits[i][j] = "Clubs";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        suits[i][j] = "Diamonds";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        suits[i][j] = "Hearts";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: At least one problem: You're incrementing `i` in you inner loop instead of `j`.

Comment: @Slaw rookie mistake haha fixed the typo

Comment: Does that fix the problem? Because I also suspect the loops should look like: `for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < deck[i].length; j++) { ... } }`.

Comment: @Slaw no but you pointing out my typo made me look throughout my code and found that the bound error was caused by initializing cards = 13; and face = 4; I changed them to 14 and 5 respectively and that corrected the error. thank you